# Array of Variable Length Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Normally, we can write this :

```
const char* names1[] = { "Stack", "LongerThanStack" };
const char* names2[] = { "Overflow", "LongerThanOverflow", "O" };
```

How to make a new array `names` that contains the above two arrays ?

Two dimensional arrays should do this.
I tried the following code, but `G++` didn't accept it because of the variable length of the inner array.

```
const char* names[2][] = {{ "Stack", "LongerThanStack" }, 
                    { "Overflow", "LongerThanOverflow", "O" }};
```

Comment: You don't have any variable length arrays here.

Comment: can (say) names3 have 4 strings instead of 3?

Comment: @juanchopanza A mistake, sorry. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Dan For both of C and C++.

Comment: @HeshamEraqi VLAs are available in C and not in C++ (atleast not yet), so please be specific. They are very different languages, so if you wanna know for both, post 2 different questions.

Comment: You should use `const char *` in C++

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Which answer do you plan to accept, the one that provides the answer for C or the one that provides the answer for C++? Remove the tag for the other language.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question to indicate it's for C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have a pressing need not to, do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> names = {{ "Stack", "LongerThanStack", "S" }, { "Overflow", "LongerThanOverflow", "O" }};
```

Comment: I've always heard people recommending the use of vectors over the use of simple arrays. Besides the obvious difference in ease of use, what's the big benefit?

Comment: @Connor Bounds checking so less bugs, dynamic size without manual memory management so no leaks.

Comment: @NeilKirk:  `vector`s don't employ bounds-checking, at least as defined by the Standard.  Some compilers (like MSVC or GCC) may have some special debugging features that can be enabled, but those features are compiler-specific.

Comment: @JohnDibling They do if you use `at` function. Technically you are correct about [].

Comment: Well, that's true.  But it will throw an exception.

Comment: @JohnDibling That's bounds checking, isn't it?

Comment: @NeilKirk  Yes, it is.

Comment: Any hints about this error :
`'names' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
          'std::vector<_Ty>' : Types with a base are not aggregate
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::vector<std::string>
          ]` ?

Comment: I can't use it because I'm forced to use a certain ARM compiler for a TOSHIBA Capricorn-Bt micro-controller. What should I do ?

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Do you need a 2d array of strings as in the example or 1d is sufficient? If 2d is the width the same for all rows?

Comment: No, I need 2D with the inner dimension of variable length.

Comment: @HeshamEraqi It looks like you are compiling for system that maybe has limited memory. Is that the case? Also, do you need the values of the strings to change at run-time?

Comment: Yes it's. No I will not change it during run-time.

Comment: @HeshamEraqi http://ideone.com/DDANp6 This shows 2 methods. One for vector, which is more flexible but uses more memory at run-time. The second, names2, will pad widths smaller than the maximum and will waste a few bytes, but unless there are many strings I would use this approach in a low-memory environment.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give them a try :-)

Answer (score 2):

Each array's dimensions exept the first one must have bounds in multidimensional array. Valid code:

```
char* names[][3] = {{ "Stack", "LongerThanStack", "S" }, 
                    { "Overflow", "LongerThanOverflow", "O" }};
```

Consider however use of containers from `STL` lib such as `Array`, `Vector`.

Comment: No, the first element number of elements is two, and the second one number of elements is three.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using C++ is preferably to use vectors
1-As fast as C Array (of course not taking into account resize, even with that, if always better that implementing yourself).
2-Memory management (automatic, tested, stable), insertion is in amortized constant time O(1).
3-Security (bound checks, debug checks, possibility of using methods that do it for your ex: at(...))
4-Iterators (possibility of using the STL), performance when using algorithms.
5-Performance (cache friendly, continuous)
6-The default container to use.

C++11 improve various problems with vectors, initializations if one that was really improved

`std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> names {{"1", "2"}, {"11", "22", "333"}, ... };`

if you need static size arrays in C++11 was added std::array.